# Is there any way to convey a certain pronunciation in the English language?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa, pronunciation-respelling

Take the sentence:

> I want to give you the best customer experience possible.

How can I change a part of the sentence so that the "the" is pronounced as "thee"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (IPA).

Alternatively, you could just add a note in the text:

> I want to give you the *[pronounced* thee*]* best customer experience possible.

Answer (score 8):

Since your desired pronunciation is the emphatic pronunciation of "the", you could simply emphasize it by italicizing it, for example.

> I want to give you *the* best customer experience possible.

Most readers would pronounce it as "thee" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The International Phonetic Alphabet is certainly precise, but I think the number of people who can actually read it is pretty darn small.

To make it accessible to a wider audience many authors will simply *respell* words so that their intended pronunciation is made clearer.  For example here's an excerpt from a book picked somewhat at random from Google books:

> [Chief, you gittin' rich; you got mo' 'n nine hun'ed dollars in gol'. Well, I say, 'gol' 's money, en money's gol'.' But he say, 'gol' 's wuff two twenty-five.'](http://books.google.com/books?id=rGoCAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22doan%27%20keer%20fer%20dat%22&pg=PA377#v=onepage&q=%22doan%27%20keer%20fer%20dat%22&f=false)

And the nice part is-  it's up to you how you spell your words *'ter git yer meenin' a'crossed.*

Comment: huntin', shootin', fishin'